# Binding an interface with Guice to a Proxy that implements it

Tags: java, reflection, proxy, guice

I have an interface class reference and an object I created using a dynamic proxy that implements the interface above.

`` final Class<?> interfaceType;
final Object interfaceImplementation = Proxy.newProxyInstance(...)` ``

I want to make the proxy instance available in the Guice application context by binding the interface to the proxy object. I tried but failed to quickly achieve this with Guice.

Is it possible to do something like:

`bind(interfaceType).toInstance(interfaceImplementation);`

so that I can inject the interface into other classes?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the return type of `Proxy.newProxyInstance()` is just `Object`, but `bind(...).toInstance(...)` wants to ensure that the type is the same as the `?` from `Class<?> interfaceType`.  At some point, you're going to need to do an unchecked cast to get everything working.  Here's how I'd write it:

```
private <T> T newProxyInstance(ClassLoader loader, InvocationHandler handler, Class<T> primaryInterface, Class<?>... extraInterfaces) {
    Class<?>[] allInterfaces = Lists.asList(primaryInterface, extraInterfaces)
            .stream()
            .toArray(Class<?>[]::new);
    @SuppressWarning("unchecked")
    T proxy = (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(loader, allInterfaces, handler);
    return proxy;
}
```

then I think

```
bind(interfaceType)
        .toInstance(newProxyInstance(loader, handler, interfaceType[, ...]));
```

would work.

Comment: Actually an unchecked cast isn't needed, you can just do `primaryInterface.cast(proxy);`

Comment: The example you listed introduces multiple interfaces which is not important so much for this discussion, but the `newProxyInstance()` precisely matches a method I have for creating the Proxy. But to get back to your suggestion, it doesn't work because you use a generic type T instead of a wild card capture. A Class<?> cannot be passed into a Class<T> parameter. Your sample code did get me closer to the solution though, thanks!

Comment: Would it be appropriate to put working code in a separate answer or does that break Stack Overflow etiquette?

Comment: @hvth "A Class<?> cannot be passed into a Class<T> parameter."  That is [not true](https://ideone.com/UyOXnR).  Anyway, feel free to put up your own answer!

Comment: Bravo Tavian, u saved my life :p